# Add a `List<Integer>` to `List<List<Integer>>`, why "new" is necessary in this situation?

Tags: java, list, copy

The question is came up when I was looking at one interview question:

Given a set of distinct integers, `nums`, return all possible subsets (the power set). And one solution is:

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        if(nums==null || nums.length==0) return res;
        dfs(res, new ArrayList<>(), 0, nums);
        return res;
    }

    private void dfs(List<List<Integer>> res, List<Integer> list, int pos, int[] nums) {
        res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));
        if(pos==nums.length+1) return;
        for(int i=pos; i<nums.length; i++) {
            list.add(nums[i]);
            dfs(res, list, i+1, nums);
            list.remove(list.size()-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here in the helper function `dfs`, we have to add a copy of the `list` each time. Otherwise, the empty list will be added to the `res` multiple times(if doing `res.add(list)` instead of what in the solution). Why "new" is necessary?

Comment: If you don't `new`, every time you add the same `list`. Try debug and you will understand.

Comment: Try changing it to just `res.add(list);` and see what happens.

Comment: I tried to make my question clear but seems its not. Did I try `res.add(list)` ? Yes, I did. It ends up with having multiple empty list in the `res`. What makes me confusing? In the first call of helper function, the `nums[0]` is added. Then it calls the function again with the list as an input. Then in the second call `res.add(list)` still add the empty the list? It seems not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a fairly standard recursive depth-first search (DFS) for all possible subsets of the set of numbers in the `nums` array.

When I run your code as it stands, it works nicely. For example I call it like this:

```
    Solution app = new Solution();
    int[] nums = { 5, 2 };

    List<List<Integer>> subsets = app.subsets(nums);
    subsets.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
[]
[5]
[5, 2]
[2]
```

And you are quite correct: if in the helper function `dfs` we don’t make a copy of the list with `new`, the result will appear as a list of empty lists. I tried changing the first line of `dfs` to just:

```
    res.add(list);
```

Now the output from the same call as above is:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

And I’ll tell you what: this is not just 4 empty lists. This is *the same* empty list being printed 4 times.

[Follow this link to see the difference live.](https://www.ideone.com/w2HTle)

**Why is this?** After all, as you said, the helper method does add elements to the list within its loop:

```
        list.add(nums[i]);
```

Without `new` *the same* list is passed to each recursive invocation of `dfs`. While elements are added to this list, they are also removed from it again:

```
        list.remove(list.size()-1);
```

So for most of the time during running your code, the result list of lists, `res` will contain a list with elements in it (the same list multiple times), at the end all the elements will be removed from the contained list.

What `new` does, as you know, is taking a copy of the list. In this way the state of the list, which elements it contains, is preserved: no elements will be removed from the copy when elements are removed from the original list. So your result ends up holding all different lists and all with the elements in them that were there when the list was added to the result.

Answer (score 0):

First, we should know the "list" used in the for loop contains an address which points to a List type.

So, when use `res.add(list)`, we store the address into the res, instead of the value. Then, every time we run `list.add(nums[i])` , we can find the change through address stored in the `list` or the address stored in `res` (actually they store the same address).

With the backtrack goes deeper, we add the same address(stored in variable `list`) repeatedly into the `res`, that's why you can find copy of the list, since they are all the same address.

So the "new" is necessary to make the res store different addresses which point to different temporary list.

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't need `new`.

I've just checked:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{


public static void addToList(List<List<Integer>> res, List<Integer> toAdd){
    res.add(toAdd);

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
    a.add(5); a.add(2);                // list a size is expected to be 2
    List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>();
    b.add(3);                           // list b size is expected to be 1

    List<List<Integer>> containerOfLists = new ArrayList<>();

    addToList(containerOfLists, a);
    addToList(containerOfLists, b);

    // Should be 2
    System.out.println("The list size is "+ containerOfLists.size());
    // Should be 2
    System.out.println("The nested list 0 size is "+ containerOfLists.get(0).size());
    // Should be 1
    System.out.println("The nested list 1 size is "+ containerOfLists.get(1).size());
    // Should be 5
    System.out.println("The nested list 0 element 0 is "+containerOfLists.get(0).get(0));
}
}
```

The result is as expected, no `new` was used in the helper and the container was not empty:

```
The list size is 2
The nested list 0 size is 2
The nested list 1 size is 1
The nested list 0 element 0 is 5
```

I don't know at what point exactly you get an empty list, but, I wonder if the problem in your case is about you creating an empty list as follows

```
 List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
```

in your `subsets` method. There you may return an empty list with the res object, and you might mistakenly think the empty list is returned by dfs. I can only suppose.

Comment: I don’t think your demo program demonstrates anything relevant. You are adding only lists that you have created with `new`.

Comment: @OleV.V., the guy is asking why, **in the helper method**, it is required to apply `new ArrayList...` to an argument, for it to be added to a list. My demo demonstrated - no, it isn't required. Please, think twice before making irrelevant comments.

Comment: When I run this guy’s code as it stands, it works. If instead I use just `res.add(list);` in the `dfs` helper method, the result is a list of all empty lists, which is very incorrect. I invite you to try. I am sorry, but I stand by my comment.

Comment: @OleV.V., thank you for taking time and reproducing the exact methods. I've mused over it and I've noted that actually the dfs helper method contains a recursive line in the **for** block, where dfs calls itself passing the current iteration `list`, and thus, all operations are done on the same list, which is empty at the start. So, you get a bunch of empty lists which in fact all point to the same place in memory - to the first iteration's value. Java works as expected. The algorithm is kind of obscured with recursion.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you! That's exactly what I was asking.

Comment: @EugeneKartoyev, I got your point. But why `list.add(nums[i]);` before the method calling itself makes no effect on the `list`? I am just confused since when the `dfs()` calls itself, the `list` should have been modified.